# Liquibase updateSQL for mysql with stored routines

Tags: mysql, database-migration, liquibase

My migrations are working perfectly but now my deployment strategy changed so I have to generate complete schema using `updateSQL` command . But it seems it does not add pre/post delimiters around a round e.g

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`;

CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' TRIGGER `labels_before_ins_tr` BEFORE INSERT ON `labels` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 ...
END 

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_upd_tr`;
```

What I expected was:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`;
delimiter ;;        
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' TRIGGER `labels_before_ins_tr` BEFORE INSERT ON `labels` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 ...
END 
;;
delimiter ;    

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_upd_tr`;
```

How we can generate this behaviour using liquibase `updateSQL` . Just to note mysql migrations are working perfectly when using `update` command

One of my migration files for trigger look like this:

```
<changeSet id="1376897476-30" author="sakhunzai" runOnChange="true" >
 <sql>DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`</sql>        
 <sqlFile endDelimiter="" splitStatements="false" path="sql/30_labels_before_ins_tr.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
 <rollback>DROP TRIGGER `labels_before_ins_tr`</rollback>           
</changeSet>
```

**Edit:**

I tweaked the migration file to generate the desired output :

```
<changeSet id="1376897476-30" author="sakhunzai" runOnChange="true" >
     <sql endDelimiter="" splitStatements="false">DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`; delimiter //</sql>        
     <sqlFile endDelimiter=" //" splitStatements="false" path="sql/30_labels_before_ins_tr.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
     <sql endDelimiter="" splitStatements="false">delimiter  ;</sql>
     <rollback>DROP TRIGGER `labels_before_ins_tr`</rollback>           
    </changeSet>
```

Now the output from `updateSQL` command looks good but `update` command give this error :

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Error executing SQL DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`; delimiter //: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter //' at line 1
```

The sql statement `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS`labels_before_ins_tr`; delimiter //` is correct in the contenxt of mysql, however `update` command fails probably it expects `;` or even `//` to terminate the statement

Finally I have only one options i.e to user a special context to be used with updateSQL command to add delimiter , that seems ugly unless I have proper solution.

Comment: a similar issue : http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/mysql-storedprocedure-sqlfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came around this solution finally to generate valid sql, which works with both update and updateSQL commands.

```
 <changeSet id="1376897476-30" author="sakhunzai" runOnChange="true" >
 <sql endDelimiter=";\ndelimiter $$">DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`</sql>        
 <sqlFile endDelimiter="\n$$\ndelimiter ;" splitStatements="false" path="sql/30_labels_before_ins_tr.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
 <rollback>DROP TRIGGER `labels_before_ins_tr`</rollback>           
</changeSet>
```

To the output from `updateSQL` will be

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `labels_before_ins_tr`;
delimiter $$        
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' TRIGGER `labels_before_ins_tr` BEFORE INSERT ON `labels` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 ...
END 
$$
delimiter ;
```